# Использовать кавычки в массиве или нет

Tags: php, массивы, кавычки

Пример 1 -

```
$products = $this->parse("get_products_by_supplier/$data[supplier_id]?quantity=$data[quantity]");
```

Пример - 2

```
$products = $this->parse("get_products_by_supplier/ " . $data['supplier_id'] . "?quantity=" . $data['quantity']);
```

Друзья доброго времени суток, вопрос вот в чем. Правильно использовать $data[supplier_id] без кавычек как в примере номер 1 или нужно только как в примере 2.

Два варианта работают

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `$products = $this->parse("get_products_by_supplier/{$data['supplier_id']}?quantity={$data['quantity']}");`

Comment: в первом случае php будет интерпретировать содержимое `[]` как имя константы. не найдёт её и выведет предупреждение. Во втором случае php будет знать что это строка и просто возьмёт значение из массива.

Comment: ArchDemon  - как ни странно работают два варианта. В первом варианте $data[supplier_id] php не определяет как константу. 

Спасибо за ответы, очень помогли мне.

Comment: Не определяет, потому что показ ошибок не включен. В официальном мануале уже давно все разжевано - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Comment: Вопросов больше нет, огромное спасибо за ссылку на документацию, и подробнейшие ответы.

Comment: Так же можно вставить в строку следующим образом: `"get_products_by_supplier/ {$data['supplier_id']}?quantity={$data['quantity']}"` - таким образом не нужно закрывать 100500 кавычек и дублировать точки, и при этом читабельность сохраняется

Comment: @Давид Манжула Но интерпретация строки в двойных кавычках будет стоить несколько дороже

Comment: @Yakoffka или наоборот: https://blog.blackfire.io/php-7-performance-improvements-encapsed-strings-optimization.html

Comment: @Мелкий Вот это поворот! (прошу прощения за оффтоп, но сказать, что я удивлен - все равно, что ничего не сказать)

Answer (score 3):

Если бы PHP только мог похвалиться консистентным поведением...

```
const SOMEKEY = 'foo';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$array = [
    'foo' => 'foo',
    'SOMEKEY' => 'bar',
];

var_dump("line 1: " . $array['SOMEKEY']);
var_dump("line 2: " . $array[SOMEKEY]);
var_dump("line 3: $array[SOMEKEY]");
var_dump("line 4: ${array[SOMEKEY]}");
var_dump("line 5: ${array['SOMEKEY']}");
```

Угадаете что произойдёт?

```
string(11) "line 1: bar"
string(11) "line 2: foo"
string(11) "line 3: bar"
string(11) "line 4: foo"
string(11) "line 5: bar"
```

[В `simple syntax`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) парсера переменных в строках нет обращения к константе, в отличии от `Complex (curly) syntax` (или обычного обращения к переменной, не встроенной в строку). В кавычки же в `simple syntax` ключ массива взять вовсе невозможно - это синтаксическая ошибка.

Оба ваших примера делают одно и то же. Но, как видно даже здесь же по комментариям, вариант `"$array[SOMEKEY]"` часто воспринимается ошибочным и чаще встречается конкатенация.